# spring boot config server production setup for error "You need to configure a uri for the git repository."

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config-server, spring-boot-configuration

I have a Spring Boot Config server that reads some properties from the local resources folder. The foldersetup is this:

- resources

  - config

    - application-production.properties
    - application.properties
  - application.properties

In resources/application.properties, I have the following:

```
spring.application.name=configserver
server.port=8012
spring.profiles.active=native
spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations=classpath:/config
```

This works just fine in dev. But in Production, in the Kubernetes manifest, I pass the following:

```
env:
  - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
    value: "production"
```

And I'm getting the following error from the pod that attempts to start this:

> 2023-02-27 22:56:43.192  INFO 1 --- [           main]
> .c.c.ConfigServerApplication : The following 1 profile is
> active: "production" 2023-02-27 22:56:48.082  INFO 1 --- [
> main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory
> id=f34714c7-eae5-36bb-b71e-023da97acc11 2023-02-27 22:56:50.190  INFO
> 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  :
> Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http) 2023-02-27 22:56:50.205
> INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService
> : Starting service [Tomcat] 2023-02-27 22:56:50.205  INFO 1 --- [
> main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet
> engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.58] 2023-02-27 22:56:50.781  INFO 1 --- [
> main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring
> embedded WebApplicationContext 2023-02-27 22:56:50.781  INFO 1 --- [
> main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root
> WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7294 ms 2023-02-27
> 22:56:57.701  WARN 1 --- [           main]
> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'defaultEnvironmentRepository' defined in
> class path resource
> [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/DefaultRepositoryConfiguration.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to configure a uri for the
> git repository. 2023-02-27 22:56:57.704  INFO 1 --- [           main]
> o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
> 2023-02-27 22:56:57.796  INFO 1 --- [           main]
> ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
> re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2023-02-27 22:56:57.993
> ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter
> :
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Invalid config server configuration.
>
> Action:
>
> If you are using the git profile, you need to set a Git URI in your
> configuration.  If you have set
> spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true, you need to use a composite
> configuration.

I don't understand enough about profiles in Spring Boot, but how do I run the config server in Production and specify native for the paths?

Comment: Can you try passing --spring.profiles.active=native as a startup parameter? this is the same as having it in the application.yml or .properties file.

Comment: I was worried that 'native' is a non-production profile, so it does work, but what if I had other settings based on a 'production' profile? What exactly is a 'native' profile anyway?! Something specifically reserved for a config server where you don't have any business code?

Comment: Maybe one cannot do what I need based on this: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1503

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable overrides `spring.profiles.active` specified in `application.properties` and thus makes `native` not active.

You should replace `spring.profiles.active` with `spring.profiles.include`.

> Sometimes, it is useful to have properties that add to the active profiles rather than replace them. The `spring.profiles.include` property can be used to add active profiles on top of those activated by the `spring.profiles.active` property.
>
> Similar to `spring.profiles.active`, `spring.profiles.include` can
> only be used in non-profile specific documents.

For reference: [Spring Docs - Adding Active Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles.adding-active-profiles)